# How to stop multiple opacity animation queue? (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

-So i have these 2 division tags.

```
<div id="div1">Hover me to show Div2</div>
<div id="div2">Div2</div>
```

-i set the opacity of div2 to 0 in CSS

-what i want to happen is when i hover div2, its opacity will go from 0 to 1

-So i put this in jQuery

```
$("#div2").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#div2).fadeTo("fast", 1);
});
```

-and when you hover out, it goes back to 0

```
$("#div2").mouseleave(function(){
    $("#div2).fadeTo("fast", 0);
});
```

-it works perfectly, but my problem is when i hover div2 more than once repeatedly, the animation is queued and it will do the hover animation over and over again

-what i want to happen is when i hover div2 again it will stop the previous animation and do a new one

how do i do it?

I can't use CSS3 transition cause i have to run it on IE9, well thanks in advance, here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twish/d8MQb/)

Comment: remove hash from id in html and use stop method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#div2").mouseenter(function(){
        $("#div2").stop( true, true ).fadeTo("fast", 1)
    });

    $("#div2").mouseleave(function(){
        $("#div2").stop( true, true ).fadeTo("fast", 0)
    });
});
```

JSFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/d8MQb/3/

Description : http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 0):

use `.stop()`:

```
$("#div2").stop().fadeTo("fast", 0);
```

and you don't need to use `#` here:

```
<div id="div2">Div2</div>
```

---

#### [Your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d8MQb/5/)

Comment: thank you it works! but how is it different from stop(true,true)?

Comment: @Twish if you go to documentation is says `.stop( [clearQueue ] [, jumpToEnd ] )` http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery clearQueue: http://api.jquery.com/clearqueue/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#div2").mouseenter(function(){
        $("#div2").clearQueue().fadeTo("fast", 1)
    });

    $("#div2").mouseleave(function(){
        $("#div2").clearQueue().fadeTo("fast", 0)
    });
});
```

Example JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d8MQb/2/